# Can you make svg images display as backgrounds... even in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, cross-browser

I'm using SVG images as background images. My CSS looks like this:

```
background:url('image.svg');
```

**The problem is that they don't appear on IE8 or earlier.**

Is there any way to make this work? Or perhaps specify a fallback only for IE? (I don't want to replace them with gifs for other browsers.)

Live example: [HERE](http://www.imadake.ca)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way I know of to make IE8 use SVG as a background image.  You have two real options if IE8 support is important to you:

1. Provide [a PNG fallback](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/06/14/using-svg-in-backgrounds-with-png-fallback/) for IE8 and other browsers which don't support SVG in a background
2. Place the SVG in your page instead of the background, position it behind everything else with CSS, then use something like [SVG Web](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) to provide support in IE8

Comment: This is really helpful. This is EXACTLY the kind of thing I was looking for. Unfortunately, option #1 is a bit too glitchy for this project, and as you pointed out #2 appears to require that the SVG images are in the HTML instead of CSS backgrounds. I might be out of luck. Before I give up thought, I just learned that <a href="http://www.modernizr.com">Modernizr</a> can test for SVG support. So this might prove fruitful in the end. Thanks for inspiring this direction of exploration.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and used [this solution](https://gist.github.com/1565894). For this to work you need to have a **[svg](http://f.cl.ly/items/0O2V262E0K0C3k0T3m1Q/twitter_newbird_blue.svg) and [png](http://f.cl.ly/items/2d0h3l051J080H2q3V2y/twitter_newbird_blue.png) copy of image**. Than write css like this:

```
.twitter-logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://cl.ly/D4xT/twitter_newbird_blue.png) no-repeat center center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url(http://cl.ly/D4o5/twitter_newbird_blue.svg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

The trick is that IE8 [doesn't support rgba](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba), and because of that **IE8 ignores second background definition**.

According to [svg support in other browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba), you will **still have issue** with *Android Browser 2.3-* and *Firefox 3.6* because they support rgba and don't support svg.

Here is **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jDGHj/)** as well.